# undefined error with ternary operator in vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, axios, undefined, conditional-operator

In my Vuejs component, I have this ternary operator in the HTML section...

```
  col.column_name == lastUpdatedFilter
                    ? secondaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
                    : primaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
```

It causes an undefined error.

> cannot read property 'firstname' of null

`firstname` is one of the column names, so I'm pretty positive this means `primaryFacetsData` and/or `secondaryFacetsData` are undefined.

However, if I replace this ternary operator with simply

```js
primaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
```

or

```js
secondaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
```

then there is no error. Why might this be?

Here is the entire relevant section of the HTML section of my Vuejs component.

```
   <div v-for="col in filterCols">
        <div :key="col.label">
          <b-row class="mb-2">
            <button
              class="accordion"
              :class="showFacet[col.column_name] ? 'active' : ''"
              @click.prevent="clickedAccordionButton(col.column_name)"
            >
              {{ col.label }}
            </button>
            <div class="panel" v-show="showFacet[col.column_name]">
              <Facet
                :isFetching="isSearching"
                :columnDef="col"
                :list="list"
                :q="q"
                :f="f"
                ref="Facet"
                @filters-changed="onFiltersChanged"
                :buckets="
                  col.column_name == lastUpdatedFilter
                    ? secondaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
                    : primaryFacetsData[col.column_name]
                "
              ></Facet>
            </div>
          </b-row>
        </div>
      </div>



<script>
...
    this.$axios
        .get("/elasticsearch/" + this.list_id, {
          params: params
        })
        .then(
          response => {
            this.isSearching = false;
            this.setSearchResults(response.data.searchResults, timesent);
            this.primaryFacetsData = response.data.primaryFacetsData;
            this.secondaryFacetsData = response.data.secondaryFacetsData;
          },
          error => {
            this.isSearching = false;
            this.searchErrorMessage = error;
          }
        );
</script>
```

It might also be helpful to note that the `primaryFacetsData` and `secondaryFacetsData` contain a lot of data.

Comment: When you did the experiment to replace the ternary operator did you do a full page refresh or just a hot reload? If it was just a hot reload then `primaryFacetsData` and `secondaryFacetsData` will already be populated so you won't have a `null`.

Comment: If you are sure you have data in `col.column_name` then just use `v-if` like eg. `<Facet v-if=''col.column_name" ...></Facet>`

Comment: @Syed Col.column_name is just a string. It always has data. The uncertainty is with the primaryFacetsData and secondaryFacetsData arrays. It seems like they sometimes do not contain data. My best guess is that when the axios request returns, these arrays clear their contents momentarily before taking the values in the axios response. Could this be what is happening? How can this be avoided?

Comment: I still like to suggest that you use `v-if` on the element/component and check if `axios` have populated your reactive data eg. `this.primaryFacetsData` || `this. secondaryFacetsData` when satisfied with your business logic only then you show/render your component in DOM. Ping me on skype if your still stuck syed_haroon